# $x_{n+1}=x_n+\cos\sqrt{|x_n|}$,How to prove $x_n$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For iterative sequence, $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=x_n+\cos\sqrt{|x_n|}$，$n=0,1,2\cdots$,prove:

$(1)$For any initial value $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$,the sequence $\{x_n\}$is convergent.

$(2)$Denote $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x^*$,then there exists a constant $C>0$,such that $|x_n-x^*|\leqslant C|f'(x^*)|^n$.

My thought:It is easy to see that when $x\neq 0$,
$f'(x)=1-\frac{\sin \sqrt{|x|}}{2\sqrt{|x|}}\mathrm{sgn} x$ and $f(x)$ is an increasing function.I tried contraction mapping principle,but it seems that if $x_n$ is large enough,there is no way to prove the existence of the constant M,such that $|f'(x)|<M<1$.Besides,it is natural to try to prove that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence,but still I don't know how to proceed.Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Key-fact: For every $t$, $|\sin t|\leqslant|t|$ hence $f$ is increasing. Second key-fact: For each $x_0$, $x_-\leqslant x_0\leqslant x_+$ with $f(x_-)=x_-$, $f(x_+)=x_+$ and, either $x_-<f(x)<x$ on $(x_-,x_+)$ or $x<f(x)<x_+$ on $(x_-,x_+)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Thanks for your help!I have known the first item!

Comment: By your help I have proved that $\{x_n\}\nearrow x^*$or $\{x_n\}\searrow x^*$,but I can't solve item 2 completely.What I have got is that when $x^*>0$,$x^*=k\pi +\frac{\pi}2$,and it's easy to discuz the fact that k must be an even number.If $\{x_n\}\nearrow x^*$,by calculating$f''(x)=\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}\cos\sqrt{x}}{4x\sqrt{x}}$ ,I can prove  $f'(x)$ is increasing in a left neighbourhood of$x^*$and associating Lagrange's mean value theorem,item 2 is solved.while if $\{x_n\}\searrow x^*$,I am stuck on it,for in this case ,$f'(x)$is still increasing in a right neighbourhood of$x^*$!

Comment: Indeed, but in this case your approach shows the weaker form $$x_n-x^*\leqslant C_nf'(x^*)^n$$ with $$C_n=c\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f'(x_k)}{f'(x^*)}$$ hence if you can prove that the increasing sequence $(C_n)$ is bounded, you are done. Now, $$f'(x_k)=f'(x^*)+f''(x^*)(x_k-x^*)+o(x_k-x^*)$$ hence $$\frac{f'(x_k)}{f'(x^*)}=1+\frac{f''(x^*)}{f'(x^*)}(x_k-x^*)+o(x_k-x^*)\leqslant e^{a(x_k-x^*)}$$ for some suitable finite $a$, hence $$C_n\leqslant c\exp\left(a\sum_{k=0}^\infty(x_k-x^*)\right)$$ and you are done since $x_k-x^*\to0$ geometrically fast.

Comment: I'm grateful for your sincere help.Now I have got it!I think it will be more rigorous if you write$f'(x_k)=f'(x^*)+f''(x^*)(x_k-x^*)+\frac12f'''(\eta_k)(x_k-x^*)^2$,$|f'''(\eta_k)|<\frac{1}{8}{x^*}^{-\frac32}+\frac38{x^*}^{-2}+\frac{3}{8}{x^*}^{-\frac52}$,thus we can pick the constant $a>\max\left\{\frac{f''(x^*)}{f'(x^*)},\frac{1}{8}{x^*}^{-\frac32}+\frac38{x^*}^{-2}+\frac{3}{8}{x^*}^{-\frac52}\right\}$,and that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$When$x\neq 0$,obviously\begin{align*}f'(x)=1-\frac{\sin \sqrt{|x|}}{2\sqrt{|x|}}\mathrm{sgn} x>0,\end{align*}Thus $f(x)$is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.Consider the roots of $\cos \sqrt{|x|}$,we get $|x|=\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$,$k\in \mathbb{Z}$.For the convience of our discussion,we denote $E=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:|x|=\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2,k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.Then $\forall x\in E$,$f(x)=x$.We discuss the value of $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$as follows.

$1^\circ$When$x_0\in E$,$x_1=f(x_0)=x_0$,$x_2=f(x_1)=x_1=x_0$,$\cdots$,$x_n=x_0$,$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.In this case $\{x_n\}$is a constant sequence,thus it must be convergent.

$2^\circ$When$x_0\not\in E$,there must exists $s,t\in E$,$(s,t)\cap E=\varnothing$,and$x_0\in (s,t) $.By the strict increasing fact of $f$,we know that $f(s)<f(x_0)<f(t)$,or $s<x_1<t$.And then $s=f(s)<f(x_1)<f(t)=t$.Notice that $(s,t)\cap E=\varnothing$,we get$x_1\not\in E$,or$f(x_1)\neq x_1$.

$(\mathrm{i})$If $f(x_1)>x_1$,i.e.$x_2>x_1$.By the fact that $s<x_1<x_2<t$and the fact that $f$ is strict increasing,we can deduce that$f(s)<f(x_1)<f(x_2)<f(t)$,or$s<x_2<x_3<t$.Using the strict growth of $f$ repeatedly,we get\begin{align*}s<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n<\cdots <t.\end{align*}It indicates that$\{x_n\}$is strict increasing,and has upper bound $t$.By monotone convergence theorem,we can see that $\{x_n\}$must be convergent.

$(\mathrm{ii})$If$f(x_1)<x_1$,i.e.$x_2<x_1$.Similar to the discussion of $(\mathrm{i})$,we can prove that$\{x_n\}$is strict decreasing,and has lower bound $s$.By monotone convergence theorem again,we can see that $\{x_n\}$must be convergent.

Question $(1)$is solved,then how about $(2)$?How can I do it?